# Running an .env file and access them from Node

Tags: node.js, linux, unix, environment-variables

This feels a bit embarrassing since I've been a Linux user for 10+ years. However, I've ran into a problem which I can't understand.

Lets assume I want to expose an environment variable, `SECRET`, that I can access from node with 
`process.env.SECRET`

I would just write this is the same terminal that I start the app with

```
# Linux bash
$ export SECRET=Ultr4Secr3t
$ echo $SECRET
$ > Ultr4Secr3t
```

Then run node app `nodejs app.js`

```js
// app.js
console.log(process.env.SECRET)
> Ultr4Secr3t
```

Everything is fine!

But I would really like to have an .env file in the repo instead.

Example .env file

```
SECRET=Ultr4Secr3t
```

```
# Linux bash
$ . .env # On Mac we had to do ". ./.env"
$ echo $SECRET
$ Ultr4Secr3t
```

Now the weird thing happens when I run the app

Then run node app `nodejs app.js`

```js
// app.js
console.log(process.env.SECRET)
> undefined
```

Why is it `undefined`? I'd rather not have to use the `dotenv` package.

Answer (score 3):

Some solutions posted before, are working, but you normally don't want to expose/polute the CLI history with some of the variables. Therefore, an `.env` file with restricted permissions might be one way to solve the problem.

To make all `.env` variables available inside `node app.js`, instead of:

```
. .env # or
source .env
```

use this:

```
export $(cat .env | xargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `. .env` you can run `source .env` such that the bash variables inside the .env file are also registered inside your main bash process from which the node process is started and inherits it's environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Node js does not support that natively. 
1) You can provide all variables in the node command when you are running the app:

```
SECRET=Ultr4Secr3t node app.js
```

Then you can access this through `process.env`

2) You can add all your config in a `config_file.json` file and then just adjust the permissions. And all what you need is to `const env = require('config_file')`

Answer (score 0):

While you're running `. ./.env`, you're actually setting them "locally". e.g:

```
// .env
SECRET=123
```

> > Environment variables set without export will not be inherited in the environment of the commands you are calling.
>
> [Source: January @ AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/205698)

When you `echo $SECRET`, it shows you the output. 
But when you `env | grep "SECRET"`, it's will not show you, it's not there in your current bash environment.

However, if you run `export SECRET=123`, it's there in your environment. Hence the `node` is able to read the environment variable `SECRET`.